# Using paramiko on a android python App

Tags: android, python, kivy, paramiko, kivy-language

I'm using buildozer to compile an Python App, and I can build the APK without problems.
In the requirements I put this:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = sqlite3,kivy,datetime,plyer,paramiko
```

But the App doesn't start. If I comment the line "import paramiko", the App starts but, obviously is not an option to me. On PC paramiko works without problem. 
I know that, for example, sqlite3 must come before kivy on requirements, right? I tried many different option like "sqlite3,paramiko,kivy,datetime,plyer" or "sqlite3,kivy,paramiko,datetime,plyer". What should I do?

EDITION:

```
Not sure if i did correctly but... I enable developer option on my phone, the adb logcat, run the App on the phone then I got: 

    05-18 10:21:49.755 20436 20436 V python  : metadata fullscreen is0
05-18 10:21:49.966 20436 20449 I python  : Starting audio thread
05-18 10:21:50.053 20436 20452 I python  : presplash-fit is null
05-18 10:21:50.054 20436 20452 I python  : presplash (fit=null) mx=0,450000,my=0,710000
05-18 10:21:50.073 20436 20452 I python  : Initialize Python for Android
05-18 10:21:50.275 20436 20452 I python  : ['/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/site-python']
05-18 10:21:50.275 20436 20452 I python  : Android path ['/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/_applibs']
05-18 10:21:50.275 20436 20452 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
05-18 10:21:50.275 20436 20452 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
05-18 10:21:50.592 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-05-18_5.txt
05-18 10:21:50.593 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
05-18 10:21:50.593 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, May 17 2016, 21:38:56) 
05-18 10:21:50.593 20436 20452 I python  : [GCC 4.8]
05-18 10:21:50.669 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
05-18 10:21:51.682 20436 20452 I python  :  /data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
05-18 10:21:51.683 20436 20452 I python  :  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
05-18 10:21:51.728 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
05-18 10:21:53.083 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
05-18 10:21:53.101 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@140.0 AU@  (GIT@I14a17c7611)>
05-18 10:21:53.102 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
05-18 10:21:53.102 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 306>
05-18 10:21:53.103 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
05-18 10:21:53.105 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
05-18 10:21:53.106 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
05-18 10:21:53.174 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Shader      ] program: <--From Vertex Shader:
05-18 10:21:53.174 20436 20452 I python  : --From Fragment Shader:
05-18 10:21:53.174 20436 20452 I python  : Link was successful.>
05-18 10:21:54.114 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
05-18 10:21:54.116 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
05-18 10:21:54.142 20436 20452 I python  : [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
05-18 10:21:54.440 20436 20452 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
05-18 10:21:54.441 20436 20452 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
05-18 10:21:54.442 20436 20452 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/app/rotinas.py", line 11, in <module>
05-18 10:21:54.443 20436 20452 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
05-18 10:21:54.444 20436 20452 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 59, in <module>
05-18 10:21:54.445 20436 20452 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 26, in <module>
05-18 10:21:54.445 20436 20452 I python  :  ImportError: No module named ecdsa
05-18 10:21:54.516 20436 20452 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

EDITION 2:

Using adb logcat | grep python (what I could copy from terminal):

```
    enter code here05-18 10:40:32.601 26849 26864 W linker  : /data/app/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap-1/lib/arm/libpython2.7.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "libpython2.7.so"
05-18 10:40:32.625 26849 26864 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_io.so"
05-18 10:40:32.642 26849 26864 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/unicodedata.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "unicodedata.so"
05-18 10:40:32.682 26849 26864 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_sqlite3.so"
05-18 10:40:32.688 26849 26864 I python  : Starting audio thread
05-18 10:40:32.709 26849 26882 I python  : Initialize Python for Android
05-18 10:40:32.974 26849 26882 I python  : ['/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/site-python']
05-18 10:40:32.974 26849 26882 I python  : Android path ['/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python27.zip', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/_applibs']
05-18 10:40:32.974 26849 26882 I python  : Android kivy bootstrap done. __name__ is __main__
05-18 10:40:32.974 26849 26882 I python  : Run user program, change dir and execute main.py
05-18 10:40:33.119 26849 26882 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_hashlib.so"
05-18 10:40:33.331 26849 26882 I python  : [ERROR             ] Error when copying logo directory
05-18 10:40:33.331 26849 26882 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
05-18 10:40:33.331 26849 26882 I python  :   File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py", line 301, in <module>
05-18 10:40:33.331 26849 26882 I python  :   File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 205, in copytree
05-18 10:40:33.331 26849 26882 I python  : Error: [('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-64.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-64.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-64.png'"), ('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-512.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-512.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-512.png'"), ('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-256.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-256.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-256.png'"), ('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-32.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-32.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-32.png'"), ('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-24.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-24.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-24.png'"), ('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-128.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-128.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-128.png'"), ('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-48.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-48.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-48.png'"), ('/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo/kivy-icon-16.png', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-16.png', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon/kivy-icon-16.png'"), '/data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/data/logo', '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/icon'"]
05-18 10:40:33.353 26849 26882 I python  : [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Older configuration version detected (0 instead of 14)
05-18 10:40:33.354 26849 26882 I python  : [WARNING           ] [Config      ] Upgrading configuration in progress.
05-18 10:40:33.372 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in /storage/emulated/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/.kivy/logs/kivy_16-05-18_0.txt
05-18 10:40:33.373 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
05-18 10:40:33.373 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.2 (default, May 17 2016, 21:38:56) 
05-18 10:40:33.373 26849 26882 I python  : [GCC 4.8]
05-18 10:40:33.391 26849 26882 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_ctypes.so"
05-18 10:40:33.436 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
05-18 10:40:34.414 26849 26882 I python  :  /data/user/0/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/core/image/img_pygame.py:13: RuntimeWarning: import cdrom: No module named cdrom
05-18 10:40:34.415 26849 26882 I python  :  (ImportError: No module named cdrom)
05-18 10:40:34.460 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_pygame (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
05-18 10:40:35.702 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: pygame
05-18 10:40:35.718 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <OpenGL ES 3.0 V@140.0 AU@  (GIT@I14a17c7611)>
05-18 10:40:35.718 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <Qualcomm>
05-18 10:40:35.719 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <Adreno (TM) 306>
05-18 10:40:35.720 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
05-18 10:40:35.721 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
05-18 10:40:35.722 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
05-18 10:40:35.791 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Shader      ] program: <--From Vertex Shader:
05-18 10:40:35.791 26849 26882 I python  : --From Fragment Shader:
05-18 10:40:35.791 26849 26882 I python  : Link was successful.>
05-18 10:40:36.725 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Support     ] Android install hooks
05-18 10:40:36.727 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
05-18 10:40:36.746 26849 26882 I python  : [INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: pygame
05-18 10:40:36.819 26849 26882 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_ssl.so"
05-18 10:40:36.953 26849 26882 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Util/_counter.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_counter.so"
05-18 10:40:36.960 26849 26882 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_AES.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_AES.so"
05-18 10:40:36.969 26849 26882 W linker  : /data/data/com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap/files/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Crypto/Cipher/_DES3.so: is missing DT_SONAME will use basename as a replacement: "_DES3.so"
05-18 10:40:37.005 26849 26882 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
05-18 10:40:37.006 26849 26882 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 12, in <module>
05-18 10:40:37.006 26849 26882 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/app/rotinas.py", line 11, in <module>
05-18 10:40:37.007 26849 26882 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
05-18 10:40:37.008 26849 26882 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 59, in <module>
05-18 10:40:37.009 26849 26882 I python  :    File "/home/awulll/dapapp/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/build/python-install/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/ecdsakey.py", line 26, in <module>
05-18 10:40:37.010 26849 26882 I python  :  ImportError: No module named ecdsa
05-18 10:40:37.080 26849 26882 I python  : Python for android ended.
05-18 10:40:37.157 26987 27003 I ActivityManager: Process com.doatlanticoaopacifico.dap:python (pid 26849) has died
```

Comment: Should I add any android permissions? I just add CAMERA. Is there any special one for ftp?

Comment: From the github repo: "It is written entirely in Python (though it depends on third-party C wrappers..." probably there isn't a recipe in p4a, so it isn't compiling and therefore the app is crushing. However, try `logcat` to get more info about it and edit your question if it's something different. Oh and... try even "INTERNET" permission.

Comment: As KeyWeeUsr said, paramiko, or one of its dependencies, requires a recipe. Someone has been having the same problem in one of the issues on the p4a github, so maybe they will contribute the necessary recipes. I think cffi is what eventually needs a recipe.

Comment: I really think this is not a recipe problem. If I had a recipe problem, would I be able to get an APK? My one is built and I can install on my Android, but it just doesn't start. I tried INTERNET permission too and nothing happens. Other guy had the same problem (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/kivy-users/1tWnZHDQuOs/WiFg4uG37YQJ) but I don't know exactly what he did - I asked him there too.. I'll try adb logcat, just need to learn how to use before, hehe. Well, later I hope have more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!

I added ecdsa on requirements:

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = sqlite3,kivy,datetime,plyer,ecdsa,paramiko
```

I don´t know if it make any difference, but I keep my permissions as:

```
android.permissions = INTERNET,ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,CAMERA
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: You can clearly see that in your logcat: `05-18 10:21:54.445 20436 20452 I python  :  ImportError: No module named ecdsa` :P

Comment: Yes! I spent some time understanding adb logcat and how enable developer debugs for my phone, but after that line it was easy. Thanks @KeyWeeUsr for the tip!

Comment: Tip #2: If you have more time and you are not sure if you have everything in requirements, do a clean install of that package to see what are the dependencies(and deps of deps, etc) and check `pip list`... or do `pip show <package>`, but it'll return only current package's deps